# How to prevent flexbox from flexing vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have the following in my page:

[image]

and they're basically two divs side by side coloured blue and orange which is made by making the outer container a flexbox.

What i want to do now is to prevent it from flexing vertically meaning if i adjust the height of the browser window, I want to prevent this:

[image]

as shown, they are becoming thinner height wise when adjusting the height of browser. How do i prevent this? Instead I want them to retain their height but just brings up a scroll bar at the side so it is scrollable height wise.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#box1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 90vh;
    background: lightblue;
}

#box2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 90vh;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container">
    <div id = "box1"></div>
    <div id = "box2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `min-height` rule

Comment: `vh` is based on the viewport, what do you expect?

Comment: @StackSlave I have to use vh or relative units because using fixed values like px is making it look different in different laptops or monitor with different dimensions

Comment: Maybe you need to know about [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)? Either that or use `min-height` and `max-height` or JavaScript based on `innerHeight` math.

Comment: you can try javascript, namely, set to 90vh, then get the height in pixels, and assign the resulting height in pixels to the blocks.

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov so its basically conversion of 90vh to pixel value with it taking into consideration the screen dimension as well?

Comment: what is it exactly that you try to achieve? DO you want the boxes to fit the content? Then I rather would recommend the use of a `css-grid` with a height of `min-content` or `auto` combines with a min-width or fixed 90vh value and set `overflow rule`.

Comment: @Maxxx, yes, you understood correctly

Comment: @tacoshy I want the two boxes to be roughly the height of 90vh in full browser screen and retain its ratio in different screen sizes and also preventing it from shrinking when the height of the browser is adjusted. Replacing vh with px does the job but i need a way where i can calculate the equivalent 90vh value in px unit for different laptop/monitor screen sizes.

Comment: I believe sergey kuznetsovs JS approach might be your only chance to do this. however I see the issue, that it would require that the browser open at full screen in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As I already wrote in the commentary, you can use javascript. If I understand correctly, then in the code I get the height in pixels for the current screen size, provided that the height is set to `90vh`. Further, the blocks (`#box1, #box2`) are assigned this height.

I don’t know, why you didn’t assign a height of `90vh` to the `#container` div. And instead they assigned each block separately. Perhaps you need it more. And according to your css, I made the code in javascript.

```js
window.onload = function() {
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
let box2 = document.querySelector('#box2');
  
  box1.style.height = box1.offsetHeight + 'px';
  box2.style.height = box2.offsetHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#box1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 90vh;
    background: lightblue;
}

#box2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 90vh;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container">
    <div id = "box1"></div>
    <div id = "box2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```