# Obtain css value "width: min-content" in px of an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get the value of an element width: 'min-content' in px. How is it calculated? I have a slide selector that modifies the css left property of a relative positioned element inside a div that has a max width of 1200px. I need to know if the difference between 1200px and left value has reached the minimum width of the element to stop it incrementing. Like:

- styles.formato.width = 1200
- styles.plato.posh contains the slide value for the left attribute

```
$('.menu-preview .menu-plato').css('max-width', styles.formato.width + 'px');
$('.menu-preview .menu-plato').css('min-width', 'min-content');
                
$('.menu-preview .menu-plato').css('width', 'calc(' + styles.formato.width + 'px - ' + (styles.plato.posh > 0 ? styles.plato.posh : (-styles.plato.posh)) + 'px)')

$('.menu-preview .menu-plato').css('left', styles.plato.posh + 'px');
```

This code just shrinks ".menu-plato" width to force break-words if it reachs the end of the parent div. But, as "left" max value is styles.formato.width, ".menu.plato" element just overflow parent.

What I want to achieve is:

```
if (element."min-width" <= (styles.formato.width - styles.plato.posh)){
    //DON'T UPDATE LEFT PROPERTY BECAUSE CHILD IS USING MIN-WIDTH AS WIDTH VALUE
    //SO IT CANNOT BE SHRUNK MORE AND LEFT ATTR WILL OVERFLOW THE ELEMENT TO THE RIGHT

}
```

I've tryed using some element node attrs like clientWidth or offSetWidth but failed because when the element width reachs the min-width value, they both hold the min-width value, but, as it's a slide selector and those attributes depends on the screen rendering, if you slide too fast, the calculations are wrong.

**EDIT**

There are more than one element with those classes, so what I've tryed is:

```
 $('.menu-preview .menu-plato').each((index, element) => {
     element.style.width = ('calc(' + styles.formato.width + 'px - ' + (styles.plato.posh > 0 ? styles.plato.posh : (-styles.plato.posh)) + 'px)');
     if (element.offsetWidth <= (styles.formato.width - (styles.plato.posh > 0 ? styles.plato.posh : (-styles.plato.posh)))) {
        if (styles.plato.posh >= 0) {
           element.style.left = styles.plato.posh + 'px'
      }
  }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: A very similar principle. Will it help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139202/how-to-prevent-flexbox-from-flexing-vertically/65139480#65139480

Comment: The code I've shown is firing on slider change. I've tryed getting offSetHeight as it holds the width value when the element is using min-width value. But, if you just slide fast, the vale of that attribute is showing wrong values (different values from real width). BTW see edited, I've added some code